# How do i render the json data on the canvas?

Tags: json, http, flutter

I just found a solution here about how to parse json data in flutter and everything is working well. Now how can i render them on my mobile screen?

I tried to make method after return statement and then call a list.builder inisde it but i couldn't made it.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(PostHome());


class PostHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My Test"),),
      body: PostScreen(),

      ),
    );
  }
}

class PostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PostScreenState createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {

  List<Post> _postList =new List<Post>();

  Future<List<Post> > fetchPost() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('http://alkadhum-col.edu.iq/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      List<dynamic> values=new List<dynamic>();
      values = json.decode(response.body);
      if(values.length>0){
        for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
          if(values[i]!=null){
            Map<String,dynamic> map=values[i];
            _postList.add(Post.fromJson(map));
            print('${map['link']}');
          }
        }
      }
      return _postList;

    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }

      @override
      void initState() {
        fetchPost();
      }


}

class Post {

  final int id;
  String title;
  String link;
  String sourceurl;


  Post({this.id, this.title, this.link, this.sourceurl});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
        id: json['id'],
        title: json['title'].toString(),
        link: json['link'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

the problem is that i don't know what i need to call inside my list.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at using the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(PostHome());

class PostHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My Test"),
        ),
        body: PostScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PostScreenState createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {
  List<Post> _postList = new List<Post>();

  Future<List<Post>> fetchPost() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('http://alkadhum-col.edu.iq/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      List<dynamic> values = new List<dynamic>();
      values = json.decode(response.body);
      if (values.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (values[i] != null) {
            Map<String, dynamic> map = values[i];
            _postList.add(Post.fromJson(map));
            print('${map['link']}');
          }
        }
      }
      return _postList;
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
      future: fetchPost(),
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            final post = snapshot.data[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(post.title),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPost();
  }
}

class Post {
  final int id;
  String title;
  String link;
  String sourceurl;

  Post({this.id, this.title, this.link, this.sourceurl});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title']['rendered'].toString(),
      link: json['link'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear.  but i got the data in this form {rendered: .....} and i need to remove rendered and the curly braces or in other way convert it to string without any curly braces only the data.